# Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted

Tags: bolt-cms

```
Error: Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 77 bytes)
File: vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/NodeVisitor/SafeAnalysis.php
Line: 47
```

I've just uploaded a site to a remote server(Ubuntu/Apache), and I'm getting the above error when the backend pages are loading. (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCb6h.png)). Frontend is working fine.

Also, many of the backend pages just show a white screen (config pages, content pages).

Any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file, adjust `memory_limit`, e.g.:

```
memory_limit = 64M
```